# Does this approach to fat model/skinny controller take it too far?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am afraid that I might be getting lazy.

I am developing a ruby on rails application involving about 8 models relating to two types of users: physicians and patients. Most of the logic is inside the models allowing my controller actions to be very short and concise. Plus, it makes the testing fairly straightforward.

I currently envision at least two controllers and the tests that I am writing lead me to believe that most of my user-facing features can be handled by these two controllers. Sure, I can break this into more sensible compartments-like tests for a patients-controller, physicians-controller, patient-medications controller, patient-lab-results-controller and so on. But it seems to me that the only advantage here is more discreet organization.

On to the question, asides from compartmentalization, what are the reasons NOT to use as few controllers as possible, pack them with lots of actions [disadvantage], but keep the actions skinny [advantage]? Or...to take it to an extreme: Why not with MVC, have a bunch of fat models, and one skinny [albeit long] controller rather than a patient controller/model/views+tests for EACH, physician controller/model/views+tests for EACH, etc?

Answer (score 2):

There's organization, as making everything inside a single controller is possible, it's going to be harder to understand and change. Instead of being able to open a file in your editor and finding the action you're looking for right away, you would be scrolling down the file to find what you're looking for.

This also leads to the **God object pattern** where everything happens inside a single object that's responsible for everything and everyone working at the project will be changing this same object, leading to an eternal merge hell.

And, on Rails itself, there's the RESTful-ness of the framework. Rails embraces the idea of being RESTful and one of the pillars of this idea are the resources and they can only be easily organized in separate controllers. If you try to place two different resources at the same controller you'll probably end up with crazy routes or crazy controller logic to find out which model is being represented.

If you think your controllers have a lot of repeated code, you can DRY them out using some metaprogramming magic or conventions, but it's really better to have them separated, not only for organization but also to simplify your own future maintenance.

Comment: Issues with maintenance and merge hell are reason enough :) OK, not only will I stick with the rules, but I see why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a lot of common controller logic, you might consider abstracting it out into a plugin or module that you can mix in when needed. Or the controllers could inherit from a common base controller (much as all controllers inherit by default from `ApplicationController`, rather than `ActionController::Base`).

I would advise against having one gigantic controller; a controller should manage the set of actions which pertain to a single type of resource (or the closest analog possible). This idea is even stronger if you are trying to create a RESTful design, in which each controller typically has nothing other than the basic seven actions (index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy).

So if you want to have URLs like `/patients/52394802/lab_results`, I think it makes complete sense to have a `LabResultsController`. If these controllers are lightweight, awesome. I'm of the opinion that their existence is still justified. This shouldn't stop you from trying to make your code DRY; rather, I would simply try to abstract away the common functionality differently.

Comment: Very valid points and sticking to a RESTful approach is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

That's an impossible question to answer. Controllers are about routes and user interactions and views not business logic. Have as many controllers and actions that it makes sense to have for your links and views!

If your business logic is all in your models then it's simple enough. The main difficulty with logic in controllers is that you can't re-use the logic.

Nothing much more to say really. It's up to you to do what makes sense in your app. e.g. have a search controller to search for stuff rather than adding a search action to your existing controllers is not really about anything more than separation and clarity